# Monotouch - Create Custom BackButton

Tags: xamarin.ios

I'm trying to create my own BackBarButtonItem, but I'm having some problems.

My declaration:

```
var backButon = new UIBarButtonItem("Back",UIBarButtonItemStyle.Plain, null, null);
```

Exception:

```
Unhandled Exception: System.ArgumentNullException: Argument cannot be null.
Parameter name: target
```

What should I put in "target" and "action" parameters?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You shouldn't use that constructor, unless you want to use the target/action pattern, I suggest:

```
public UIBarButtonItem (string title, UIBarButtonItemStyle style, EventHandler handler)
```

which you use like:

```
var btn = new UIBarButtonItem ("Back", UIBarButtonItemStyle.Plain, delegate (object sender, EventArgs e) {
    Console.WriteLine ("button clicked");
});
```